# Gauge transformation and phase matching in cylinder coordinate for the Aharonov-Bohm Effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, boundary-conditions, gauge-invariance

I'm trying to get through Sakurai The Aharonov-Bohm Effect where on page 141.

According t0 Eq 2.7.53, if the original equation was transformed by a gauge $\tilde A=A+\nabla \Lambda$, then the solution for the new system was just the original solution at $\Lambda=0$ multiplied by a phase, i.e. 
$$|\alpha,\tilde{t_0}; t\rangle =\exp(\frac{ie\Lambda }{\hbar c})|\alpha,t_0; t\rangle$$

However, suppose in an concentric cylinder, with $B\hat{z}$ presented in the center within boundary $\rho_a$ and $0$ otherwise, where the system was confined between $(\rho_a,\rho_b)$.

With $B=0$, the $\phi$ dependent part the of the solution was just $e^{im \phi}$ where $m$ was an integer. 
According to Eq 2.7.53, with $B\neq 0$, $\Lambda =\frac{B\rho_a^2}{2 } \phi$, and the $\phi$ dependent part of the solution was 
$$e^{i\frac{e}{\hbar c} \frac{B\rho_a^2}{2}\phi} e^{im\phi}.$$

However, this seemed to be problematic as the boundary condition for which $\phi\in [0,2\pi]$ was no longer satisfied if $\frac{e}{\hbar c} \frac{B\rho_a^2}{2}$ was not an integer.

What went wrong? Why the equation didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at problem 28.c

If you require the ground state energy to be unchanged by the presence of $B$, then you require the boundary condition to hold.

So:
$$\frac{e}{\hbar c}\frac{B \rho_a^2}{2} = m \in \mathbb{Z} \quad \implies\quad\pi \rho_a^2B=\frac{2\pi m\hbar c}{e}, $$
which is known as *flux quantisation*.

Experimental proof from [here](http://www.fizika.unios.hr/kvm2/wp-content/uploads/sites/76/2015/11/The-Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm-effects.pdf):

[image]